# text classification problem with product description

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification

I am new to machine learning, I have a dataset with 4000-5000 items, they are all product descriptions, and the result
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvqhF.png), I want to train a model to classify them into 1 or 0, can I train it with this kind of text?

Comment: Please Update your question with further information on the problem you are facing. What are the classes 0 and 1? What is your description exactly made of?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can! The keyword you are searching for is sentiment analysis. Take a look at this [article](https://huggingface.co/blog/sentiment-analysis-python) by huggingface for sentiment analysis in python with a pre-trained model and from scratch.

### Using pretrained models

1. Install the huggingface transformers python package `pip install -q transformers`
2. Import the sentiment-analysis pipeline provided by huggingface, which already implements publicly available models on huggingface:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
```

3. Inference

```py
data = [PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_1, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_2, ...]
results = sentiment_pipeline(data)
```

4. Results then contains an array of objects with a property "label" ("POSITIVE"/"NEGATIVE") and "score" (confidence score). In order to retrieve ratings (1-5) you either have to implement some sort of gausian random distribution to generate stars based on the positive/negative ratings (e.g. positive: mean of 4 with a variance of 1, negative: 2 with a variance of 1).

### Fine-tuning model

To achive better results than using binary classification and randomness to provide ratings in form of stars, you would likely need to fine-tune an existing machine learning model for sentiment-analysis. Fine-tuning in this context means, that you build up on an existing models with existing weights and use an own, smaller dataset to fit the existing models to your special needs. You can do this with the huggingface library as well:

1. Install python packages `pip install datasets transformers huggingface_hub`
2. Preprocess your own dataset by shuffling your samples, splitting a test and train set
3. Tokenize the dataset (our model doesn't understand words, so we kind of need to encode them first. A usual practice doing so, is to use one-hot encode every single word in a high dimensional vector or to assign every word an index). As these kind of machine learning models expect the input to have a predefined length, we need to pad shorter sentences (usually done with a special

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")

def preprocess_function(examples):
   return tokenizer(examples["text"], truncation=True)
 
tokenized_train = small_train_dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)
tokenized_test = small_test_dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)

data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

4. We can then start the training process based on a pretrained model called "distilbert", but with 5 output labels (1 label equals 1 possible rating):

```py
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased", num_labels=5)
```

5. Now we can finally start the training process:

```py
training_args = TrainingArguments(
  output_dir="my-model",
  learning_rate=2e-5,
  per_device_train_batch_size=16,
  per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
  num_train_epochs=5, # adjust this parameter to your desired training length
  weight_decay=0.01,
  save_strategy="epoch",
  push_to_hub=False,
)

trainer = Trainer(
  model=model,
  args=training_args,
  train_dataset=tokenized_train,
  eval_dataset=tokenized_test,
  tokenizer=tokenizer,
  data_collator=data_collator,
)

trainer.train()
trainer.save_model("my-model")
```

6. You can then use the model to inference with the difference, that you will receive results with more than 2 classes:

```py
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("my-model")
results = model(data)
```

Source: [huggingface blog](https://huggingface.co/blog/sentiment-analysis-python)

### Comment section summarization

As their was a misunderstanding on the problem the question author is facing, here a summarization of the discussion in the comments:
The author want's to predict review ratings (1-5 stars) based on product DESCIRPTIONS. As - **in my opinion** - descriptions and the resulting reviews aren't related (descriptions are always written positive, to sell the products they describe). I think that therefor no prediction based on the description itself is possible, and further inputs are needed (e.g. overall product "quality", utility of the product, etc.).

Comment: my concern is that the product description does not contain any emotional wording like sentiment analysis for classification, Is it still okay to train it?

Comment: Then may I ask: When is a description positive and when negative? And what is the rating about? Is it the quality of the description or reviews of the product the description relates to?

Comment: I want to define it as positive when the rating equals 5, and the other is negative, the rating is rated by the customers.

Comment: why you need machine learning then? Just compare the rating: ```isPositive = rating == 5```

Comment: you may misunderstand my answer.  I want to build a  model that can predict whether it is positive or negative  based on the description

Comment: Okay but that's my question: how do you define a "positive" prediction? You told, me that you want to label it as a positive when the rating equals 5. But for this task, you won't need machine learning. Do you want to predict the rating? Or do you just wanna have the description and let the ml model decide? If you mean the last, again, how do you define, that a description (NOT a review) is positive? Positive in the meaning of "helpful"? Positive in the manner of "the product is described positive"? You need to clarify your needs in your question about what the input and the predicted outcome

Comment: i want to predict the rating

Comment: Okay you said, that the rating comes from the customers. How do you want the rating to be generated then?

Comment: I want to do it like the example that you give above like the sentimental analysis, after I trained the model when I input the description it returns rating

Comment: You can do this with the article I linked in the answer, and instead of binary classification (positive/negative), you modify the example with the multi-class prediction (each class represents a possible star. So you would have 5 classes (1 star, 2 stars, ...)). But again: In machine learning input and output need to be related. I need to be able to guess the output given an input. How is the rating of a review related to a description? Isn't it related more to the product itself?

Comment: oh you are meaning two of them are unrelated, but the description contains some text like the design or clothing material, do you think that it can be used for the rating prediction?

Comment: Hmm I guess that the rating is rather related to the product itself than the description of the product. Why do you need a prediction of the rating?

Comment: because I want to predict the new arrival's rating base on description, or do you think that the brand name, product name, the price , and the color are more related to the rating?

Comment: It may be possible for extreme examples, but as product descriptions are written to always sound positive (because the retailer wants to sell his product). Because of that, I can't imagine that it would work. But when your dataset is labeled, there's nothing wrong with just trying it out.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks for reaching out with this hint! I updated the answer according your suggestions for improvement.